# How to add Cloud Storage Provider to Windows 10 Navigation Pane

Tags: windows-10, cloud

I want to add [Stack Storage](https://www.transip.nl/stack/) to my Windows 10 navigation pane, as is shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn889934(v=vs.85).aspx). So I want it to appear just like Dropbox and OneDrive. Now, obviously this is a 'guide' already, but since I don't have any experience with the registry, I hope someone could help me out on a few points.

1. In step 1, How do I generate this CLSID? Sorry, but I really don't know. Also, should the curly brackets remain?
2. In step 2, I assume I can provide a path to a .dll starting from C:\ ? Then, how do I know what this identifier should be, which is 1043 in the example?
3. In step 6, should I change that second ID that is in curly brackets?
4. In step 8, Can I also start the path from C:\ here? So I mean it would be something like C:\Users\iris_\stack
5. In step 10, I don't really understand how to set all these flags?

I really hope someone can help me out with these points.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I hope someone could help me out on a few points.

> 1. In step 1, How do I generate this CLSID? Sorry, but I really don't know. Also, should the curly brackets remain?

Use `Uuidgen.exe.` as instructed.

The uuidgen utility (Uuidgen.exe) is automatically installed when you install the Platform Software Development Kit (SDK).

The curly braces `{` and `}` are not part of the CLSID (the CLSID is a 128-bit number, in hex, within a pair of curly braces)

> 2. In step 2, I assume I can provide a path to a .dll starting from C:\ ? Then, how do I know what this identifier should be, which is 1043 in the example?

It is the resource ID for an image that is in your DLL.

> 3. In step 6, should I change that second ID that is in curly brackets?

I don't think so. `{0E5AAE11-A475-4c5b-AB00-C66DE400274E}` appears to be an existing CLSID that is related to `%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll`.

> 4. In step 8, Can I also start the path from C:\ here? So I mean it would be something like C:\Users\iris_\stack

I would use `%%PUBLIC%%\MyCloudStorageApp` (%PUBLIC% is `C:\Users\Public`) if you want it to be for all users.

> 5. In step 10, I don't really understand how to set all these flags?

The flags value (in this example `0xF080004D`) is obtained by adding together the hex values of the flags you want to use.

You can use the Windows Calculator in
"View" > "Programmer" and enable "Hex" mode to perform the calculations for the flags value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Step 1: I have installed the Platform SDK and have located 3 instances of Uuidgen.exe. If I try to open one, I see a command prompt for a split second but that's it. Doesn't do anything...
Step 2: I understand, but how do I find this? I have no clue..
Step 8: C:\Users\iris_\stack is where my stack already is.. so should it be this path?

Comment: @IrisHijne `uuidgen` is a command line program, so you have to open a `cmd` prompt and then run it. `uuidgen /?` will give you the help for running the command. Note you may have to use the full path, for example `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\uuidgen.exe" /? `. `uuidgen` run from the command line will just generate one for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have a CLSID now. But I still have no clue how to get the resource identifier for the icon (step 2)... I know it is in a .dll file but that is all I know.

Comment: @IrisHijne Open your dll file in something like [ResourceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and browse the icons. You should see a number (which will be the ResourceID)

Comment: You're fast! Before I read your comment I just found something myself.. The icon is in a different file than I thought it was, it is in an .exe. I can find 6 icons in there, can it be that the ID's are simply 1 to 6? Do you by any change know which size I should choose? (16x16, 32x32 or 48x48)

Comment: @IrisHijne No idea.

Comment: Can I change this in the registry until it is right? Because then I'll just try, since there's only six..

Comment: @IrisHijne Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Everything is working except for the icon, it won't show. But thanks so much for all your help!